# Symfony2: memory exhausted in the renderer

Tags: performance, symfony, memory

I have a page in Symfony2 that display a list of search result in a table. I use the JS library gridify to display the result so I have no troubles with the browser, but with Symfony2.

When I have many results (eg 40 000), I have an exception

```
php.CRITICAL: Fatal Error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 59233802 bytes)
```

thrown from PhpEngine->evaluate which does:

```
ob_start();
require $this->evalTemplate;
$this->evalTemplate = null;
return ob_get_clean();
```

The memory exception occures on ob_get_clean. I think that the included template is too huge to be included. The memory limit is currently to 512M, I don't want to increase it once more (but with 1024M I have no more problems).

Is there any way (proper or not) in Symfony2 to bypass it?

Comment: Memory is a hard limit. You cannot bypass it, yet if you would share how you generate your result set it may be possible to optimize it. In the end, make sure if you really need 40,000 results at once. As it stands, I think this question is a bit too broad.

Comment: You should paginate the result

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can increase the memory_limit at runtime with this line of code:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M')
```

but the hosting provider may have put in place some ways to prevent that.

Anyway, as other have suggested, you may want to find out why so much memory is consumed and possibly optimize the whole process.